# how to generate a dynamic host inventory in ansible awx on a local network with local DNS server

Tags: dns, ansible

My environment:

**Hosts:** approximately 78-100 Linux hosts with dynamic IPs

**Severs:** FreeIPA server with DNS enabled. The linux desktops use this FreeIPA server as a domain controller as well as dns server.

**Ansible AWX:** Ansible AWX (upstream version of Ansible Tower).

**Problem:** i want to create an inventory (smart?) in ansible AWX with hosts pulled from the DNS server (FreeIPA)

OR

scan the network IP range say 192.168.1.50 - 192.168.1.220 and create an inventory. There are some filters i may need to apply for example, i would want only hosts whose FQDN belongs to a particular domain e.g host1.exa.com.

I've read about the nmap plugin but the example is so lacking that i cant figure it out.
Note: Not all machines are always on. As such every-time i want to run a playbook i am forced to use an ip scanner, export the file manually into awx_task & import it into a new inventory. This is tedious & inefficient.
Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: Did you actually have a look at the [contrib script in ansible distribution](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/stable-2.9/contrib/inventory/freeipa.py) ? The script containing folder is linked from the [documentation page on dynamic inventories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#other-inventory-scripts). You can also have a look at a [still pending PR for an other contrib](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/41766)

Comment: @Zeitounator  Yes and it doesn't address my issue. Though am new to ansible awx, i've managed to setup FreeIPA client successfully. So am not at zero. The scripts am looking at dont tell me how to adopt to my situation or even how to implement it. Am i missing something?

Comment: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/dev_guide/developing_inventory.html#developing-inventory

Answer (score 0):

In regards to your "Scan the network" option, perhaps you can take a look at the nmap plugin for Ansible / AWX

I have not tested it myself yet, but looks very promising.

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/inventory/nmap.html

Comment: Please try to write the relevant stuff from the link in your answer. Links have a chance of becoming invalid in the future.